# iOS Abandoned memory VM: Image IO

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, abandoned-memory

I have a such kind of problem. I`m developing an iPad application which actually uses a lot of images and core animation stuff. I have no leaks but I have abandoned memory issue. I have a steady memory growth. I have disabled animations that  actually use quite a lot of memory but I still have problems with memory growth. For animations I use http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/mpfoldtransition/.  I have replaced implementations of such loading methods in UIImage class as "imageNamed:" etc. Still it does not help.

If anyone has any ideas please help.

Thanks to everybody.

[image: Instruments screenshot]

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name {
    NSString *pathExtension = [name pathExtension];
    name = [name stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    if ([pathExtension isEqualToString:@""]) {
        pathExtension = @"png";
    }

    NSString *sufix = [BMKAppUtilites isRetina] ?  @"@2x" : @"";
    name = [name stringByAppendingString:sufix];
    name = [name stringByAppendingPathExtension:pathExtension];

    name = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[name stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[name pathExtension]];
    return [[self alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:name options:NSDataReadingUncached error:NULL] scale:[BMKAppUtilites scaleFactor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: I just noticed this question is over 6 years old.

—

It looks a lot like something still has a strong reference to your images. I’d say your best bet based on the data you’ve shown us is to just run from Xcode and pause in the memory graph to see what has the strong references. Don’t forget to turn on malloc stack traces in your scheme in order to get traces to where the memory is allocated. Good luck.

This might help a bit if you’ve never used the Xcode memory graph: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving_your_app_s_performance/reducing_your_app_s_memory_use/gathering_information_about_memory_use